# PrePersist method fails to save modified values in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Can someone please explain why the following does not work?

I have a domain object with several transient fields that contain complex POJOs. When the comain object is saved, I want to serialize these objects to XML (using Xstream), and store them into a PersistentMap in my database.

So i create a @PrePersist/@PreUpdate method on my domain object, and in those methods serialize the values and place them into the persistent map in the domain object. When the persist is called, I can see the values get serialized, the map gets updated, but the actual values saved are the original values, not the updated ones.

My assumption is that since the change is happening in the PrePersist/PreUpdate methods, the underlying persistence provider (in my case Hibernate 3) determines the changed fields in the domain prior to calling the PrePersist/PreUpdate method, and so when the actual save is done, the original values are never updated.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to make this work? Is there some other mechanism I can use other than the PrePersist/PreUpdate hooks?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If only transient values changed Hibernate will not think the object has changed and as a result will not call `@PreUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to get this to work was to actually change the state on the event.

```
String[] names = event.getPersister().getPropertyNames();
for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if ("myProperty".equals(names[i])) {
        event.getState()[i] = getMyProperty();
    }
}
```